# Coin change problem with specific multiples

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

##### Background

There are coins with value of 1, 5, 10, 20, 50, 100.

Asking for how many ways are there to make up 10000?

---

The answer is 174716753951.

As far as I know this is equivalent to finding the 10000th term of the following generating function:

And the formula for general term will be very complicated and can only be solved by recursion.

$$
G(x) = \frac{1}{(1-x) \left(1-x^5\right) \left(1-x^{10}\right) \left(1-x^{20}\right) \left(1-x^{50}\right) \left(1-x^{100}\right)}
$$

But the solution gives a formula, if n is a multiple of 100, then there is:

$$g_{n|100}=\frac{50 n^5}{3}+\frac{475 n^4}{6}+\frac{265 n^3}{2}+\frac{551 n^2}{6}+\frac{137 n}{6}+1$$

The solution does not give more explanation.

##### Question

I want to know how this polynomial is obtained.

Under what circumstances will I get such a polynomial, I tried $n|50$, and there is no polynomial relationship under 100 degree.

Comment: Mathologer solves a similar question (but using a different set of coin values) in the YouTube video [Explaining the bizarre pattern in making change for a google dollars](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VLbePGBOVeg).

Comment: @GalAster I have the full answer now. If you like I can add that to my partial answer. lmk.

Comment: @Galster, if you have a look at my answer below, you find with how you can derive the polynomial from $G(x)$. There is no single polynomial for the case n|50, in stead you get two similar but different polynomials for the odd and even values of n.

Answer (score 3):

This is a partial answer.
First we can rewrite $G(x)$ as

$G(x) = (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)\frac{1}{(1-x^5)^2 \left(1-x^{10}\right) \left(1-x^{20}\right) \left(1-x^{50}\right) \left(1-x^{100}\right)}$

Since in the denominator, the powers of $x$ are multiples of $5$, the only way to get a multiple of $10000$ is to multiply $1$ from first factor with $x^{10000}$ from second.

Ignore the first term for now. Let $y = x^5$

We get $\frac{1}{(1-y)^2 \left(1-y^2\right) \left(1-y^4\right) \left(1-y^{10}\right) \left(1-y^{20}\right)}$

Using $(1-y)(1 + y + \cdots + y^{19}) = 1 - y^{20}$

and $(1-y^2)(1 + y^2 +\cdots + y^{18}) = 1 - y^{20}$ etc.

we get

$(1 + y + \cdots + y^{19})^2(1 + y^2 + \cdots + y^{18})(1 + y^4 + \cdots + y^{16})(1 + y^{10})\frac{1}{\left(1-y^{20}\right)^6}$

Now we have to find coefficient of $y^{2000}$. This can be painstakingly done to find the answer.

The coefficient of ${(y^{20})}^n$ in last factor $= \binom{n+5}{n}(-1)^{2n} = \frac{n^5 + 15n^4 + 85n^3 + 225n^2 + 274n + 120}{120}$

The coefficient of ${(y^{20})}^{n-1} = y^{20n-20}$ in last factor $= \binom{n+4}{n-1}(-1)^{2n-2} = \frac{n^5 + 10n^4 + 35n^3 + 50n^2 + 24n}{120}$

The coefficient of ${(y^{20})}^{n-2} = y^{20n-40}$ in last factor $= \binom{n+3}{n-2}(-1)^{2n-4} = \frac{n^5 + 5n^4 + 5n^3 -5 n^2 -6n}{120}$

The coefficient of ${(y^{20})}^{n-3} = y^{20n-60}$ in last factor $= \binom{n+2}{n-2}(-1)^{2n-6} =\frac{n^5 - 5n^3 +4n}{120}$

The coefficient of ${(y^{20})}^{n-4} = y^{20n-80}$ in last factor $= \binom{n+1}{n-3}(-1)^{2n-8} =\frac{n^5 -5n^4 + 5n^3 + 5n^2 -6n}{120}$

The (-1) factor will always be positive.

The terms that matter in the product of all the other terms are:

$4y^{80} + 432 y^{60} + 1225 y^{40} + 338 y^{20} + 1$

The coefficient of $n^5$ $= \frac{1 + 338 + 1225 + 432 + 4}{120} = \frac{50}{3}$

The coefficient of $n^4$ $= \frac{15 + 338*10 + 1225*5 -20}{120} = \frac{475}{6}$

The coefficient of $n^3$ $= \frac{85+ 35*338 +5*1225 -5*432 + 5*4}{120} = \frac{265}{2}$

The coefficient of $n^2$ $= \frac{225 + 50*338 - 5*1225 +20 }{120} = \frac{551}{6}$

The coefficient of $n$ $= \frac{274 + 24*338 -6*1225 +4*432 -6*4}{120} = \frac{137}{6}$

The constant is $120/120 = 1$

Comment: Is there any way one can use this method to obtain the polynomial mentioned in the question?

Comment: yes. I have the full answer now. Should I add it to my answer?

Comment: @sku I would be very curious to see the full answer, so I think you should add it.

Answer (score 3):

Getting the answer is indeed a bit of work, but less than you might expect based on the other answers, and it can all be done without computers or programs. Key of this problem however understanding the function $G(x)$ and its meaning. For $|x|<1$ the function can be written as an infinite series
\begin{eqnarray}
G(x) & = & \frac{1}{(1-x)(1-x^5)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{20})(1-x^{50})(1-x^{100})} \\ \\
& = & (1+x+x^2+x^3+\dots)(1+x^5+x^{10}+\dots) (1+x^{10}+x^{20}+\dots) \times \\ & & \qquad (1+x^{50}+x^{100}+\dots) (1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)\\ 
& = & \sum_{k=0}^\infty c_k x^k
\end{eqnarray}
where the coefficient $c_k$ gives you the number of different ways in which the coins will add up to the total amount $k$.

Using a computer program, one could now make that expansion and look for the relevant coefficients. But we can also do without a computer, but a little more effort.  Here we are interested in the case that $k$ its a multiple of 100. That means that we do not really need to know all coefficients $a_k$ but only those for which $k= 100 n$.

What follows might look complicated, but each step is simple, so don't be discouraged by the big formulas.

First we are going to write $G$ in a more convenient form:

\begin{eqnarray}
G(x) 
& = & \frac{(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4)}{(1-x^5)^2(1-x^{10})(1-x^{20})(1-x^{50})(1 -x^{100})} \\ \\
& = & \frac{(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4) (1+x^5)^2}{(1-x^{10})^3(1-x^{20})(1-x^{50})(1 -x^{100})} \\ \\
& = & \frac{(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4) (1+x^5)^2 (1+x^{10})^3}{(1-x^{20})^4(1-x^{50})(1 -x^{100})} \\ \\
& = & \frac{(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4) (1+x^5)^2 (1+x^{10})^3 (1+x^{10} +x^{20}+x^{30} + x^{40})^4}{(1-x^{50})(1 -x^{100})^5} \\ \\
& = & \frac{(1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4) (1+x^5)^2 (1+x^{10})^3 (1+x^{20} +x^{40}+x^{60} + x^{80})^4(1+x^{50})}{(1 -x^{100})^6}\\ \\
& = & (1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4) (1+x^5)^2 (1+x^{10})^3 (1+x^{20} +x^{40}+x^{60} + x^{80})^4(1+x^{50}) (1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)^6
\end{eqnarray}

We are only interested in powers of $x^{100 n}$ , so we can remove all others. In the last line every factor, except the first, only contains terms where the exponents of $x$ are multiples of 5, i.e.,$x^{5n}$. That means that of the first factor only the 1 can be used and the rest $x+x^2+x^3+x^4$ will never result in a term with a correct exponent. Essentially, this means that the coin of value 1 is always used in multiples of 5. So we know that
\begin{eqnarray}
G(x) & \doteq & (1+x^5)^2 (1+x^{10})^3 (1+x^{20} +x^{40}+x^{60} + x^{80})^4(1+x^{50}) (1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)^6
\end{eqnarray}
where I use $\doteq$ to signify that the equality is true for all terms of the form $x^{100n}$ (but not for others). We can repeat the same idea, but now for terms of the form $10^{10n}$.
\begin{eqnarray}
G(x) 
& = & (1+ 2 x^5 + x^{10}) (1+x^{10})^3 (1+x^{20} +x^{40}+x^{60} + x^{80})^4(1+x^{50}) (1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)^6 \\ \\
& \doteq & (1 + x^{10}) (1+x^{10})^3 (1+x^{20} +x^{40}+x^{60} + x^{80})^4(1+x^{50}) (1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)^6\\ \\
& = & (1+x^{10})^4 (1+x^{20} +x^{40}+x^{60} + x^{80})^4(1+x^{50}) (1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)^6\\ \\
& = & (1+4 x^{10} + 6 x^{20} + 4 x^{30} + x^{40}) (1+x^{50})(1+x^{20} +x^{40}+x^{60} + x^{80})^4 (1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)^6\\ \\
& = & (1+4 x^{10} + 6 x^{20} + 4 x^{30} + x^{40}+ x^{50}+4 x^{60} + 6 x^{70} + 4 x^{80} + x^{90}) \times \\ &  & \qquad (1+x^{20} +x^{40}+x^{60} + x^{80})^4 (1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)^6 \\ \\
& \doteq & (1+ 6 x^{20} + x^{40}+ 4 x^{60} + 4 x^{80}) (1+x^{20} +x^{40}+x^{60} + x^{80})^4 (1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)^6
\end{eqnarray}
where we in the last line removed, just like before, those terms in the first factor that could not give rise to terms of the type $x^{20n}$ as found in the last two factors.

For the last step we need to expand the  first two factors and only keep those that are of the form $x^{100n}$. This is not difficult, but a bit of careful work.

\begin{eqnarray}
G(x) 
& = & (1+10 x^{20}+35 x^{40} +88 x^{60}+185 x^{80}+338 x^{100}+535 x^{120}+760 x^{140}+ \\ & & \qquad 981 x^{160}+1150 x^{180} + 1225 x^{200}+1200 x^{220}+1075 x^{240}+874 x^{260} + \\ & & \qquad 645 x^{280}+432 x^{300}+255 x^{320}+130 x^{340}+57 x^{360}+20 x^{380}+   4 x^{400}) \times \\ & & \qquad (1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)^6\\ \\
G(x) & \doteq  & (1+338 x^{100} + 1225 x^{200}+432 x^{300}+ 4 x^{400})
(1+x^{100}+x^{200}+\dots)^6 \\
& = & \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_{100n} x^{100n}
\end{eqnarray}

So all we have to do now is to determine the $c_{100n}$. First we clean this a bit up by $y \equiv x^{100}$ and $b_n \equiv c_{100n}$.

\begin{eqnarray}
G^*(y) & \doteq  & (1+338 y + 1225 y^2+432 y^3+ 4 y^4)    (1+y + y^2 + y^3 + \dots)^6 \\ \\
& = & \sum_{n=0}^\infty b_n y^n
\end{eqnarray}

In order to proceed we focus on the expansion of the last term
$$
(1+y + y^2 + y^3 + \dots)^6 = \frac{1}{(1-y)^6} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n y^n
$$
then we just have a Taylor series of the function. Hence, the coefficients $a_n$ are given by
$$
a_n = \frac{1}{n!} \frac{d^n}{d y^n} \left.\left( \frac{1}{(1-y)^6} \right)\right|_{y=0} =  \frac{1}{n!} \frac{(n+5)!}{5!}  \left.\left( \frac{1}{(1-y)^{n+6}}\right)\right|_{y=0} = \frac{(n+5)!}{n!5!}
$$

So turning back to $G^*(y)$ we find that
\begin{eqnarray}
G^*(y) & \doteq  & (1+338 y + 1225 y^2+432 y^3+ 4 y^4) (1 + \dots + a_{n-4} y^{n-4} + a_{n-3} y^{n-3} + a_{n-2} y^{n-2} + a_{n-1} y^{n-1} + a_{n} y^{n} + \dots )
\end{eqnarray}
Therefor the coefficient $b_n$ is given by
\begin{eqnarray}
b_n & = &  a_n + 338 a_{n-1} + 1225 a_{n-2} + 432 a_{n-3} + 4 a_{n-4}\\ \\
& = & \frac{50}{3} n^5 + \frac{475}{6} n^4 + \frac{265}{2} n^3 + \frac{551}{6} n^2+\frac{137}{6}n + 1
\end{eqnarray}

In a similar fashion, you can also obtain an expression for the case when you are using a multiple of 50, in stead of a multiple of 100. However, the problem is here that there is not a single expression for all combinations. In stead, you get two different ones.

\begin{eqnarray} 
c_{50n} &= &\frac{1}{96} \left( 50 n^5 + 475 n^4 + 1590 n^3 + 2204 n^2 + 1096 n + 57\right) & \qquad \text{for $n$ is odd}\\
c_{50n} &= &\frac{1}{96} \left( 50 n^5 + 475 n^4 + 1590 n^3 + 2204 n^2 + 1096 n + 96\right) & \qquad \text{for $n$ is even}
\end{eqnarray}

The second one is just what we found before by replacing $n$ by $2 n$.

Answer (score 2):

A way to obtain such a polynomial solution for a currency with denominations $a_1\leq...\leq a_m$ is to have $a_m=\text{lcm}(a_1,..,a_{m-1})$. This clearly holds in the above. To illustrate the procedure of obtaining a solution, let us find the number of ways to get $10n~,~ n\in \mathbb{N}$ with denominations $(1,5,10)$.

It is clear that this is equivalent to finding the cardinality of the set of distinct quadruplets $(a,b,c,d)$ such that

$$a+5b+10c=10n$$

We consider $b$ modulo 2 and we notice that $a$ is determined modulo 10:

$$b=2m_1\Rightarrow a=10m_2\\b=2m_1+1\Rightarrow a=10m_2+5$$

Plugging into the original equation we see that we need to solve two separate, but much simpler problems

$$m_1+m_2+m_3=n~~~,~~~ 0\leq m_1,m_2,m_3\leq n\\m'_1+m'_2+m'_3=n-1~~~~,~~~~~0\leq m'_1,m'_2,m'_3\leq n-1$$

The number of distinct k-tuplets that satisfy $m_1+...+m_k=n$ is $n+k\choose k$. Thus we find out that the number of solutions to the original problem is surprisingly

$${n+2\choose 2} + {n+1\choose 2}=(n+1)^2$$

The same procedure can be generalized to solve the most general case, albeit with increasingly tedious casework. Specifically, for the problem at hand with denominations $(1,5,10,20,50,100)$ it is equivalent to find the non-negative solutions of the Diophantine equation

$$a+5b+10c+20d+50e+100f=100n$$

Here we need to consider $e$ modulo 2, $d$ modulo 5, $c$ modulo 10 and $b$ modulo 20 and the problem reduces to $2\times 5\times10\times 20=2000$ subcases that can be solved separately. It can be easily shown that the total number of solutions is given by

$$N_1{n+5\choose 5} + N_2{n+4\choose 5}+N_3{n+3\choose 5} + N_4{n+2\choose 5}+ N_5{n+1\choose 5} $$

where the $N_i's$ are some natural numbers that sum to $2000=\text{lcm}(5,10,20,50)^4/(5\cdot 10\cdot 20\cdot 50)$.
I haven't found an elegant algorithm to count these numbers (it is clear however that $N_1=1$), so instead I wrote a piece of Mathematica code that computes these numbers by checking every single case, whose output is exactly the polynomial quoted above.

```
w = Table[#*i, {i, 0, 100/# - 1}] & /@ {50, 20, 10, 5};

temp = Table[w[[1, i]] + w[[2, j]] + w[[3, k]] + w[[4, l]] + 
Mod[100 - Mod[w[[1, i]] + w[[2, j]] + w[[3, k]] + w[[4, l]], 100],
  100] 
, {i, 1, Length[w[[1]]]}, {j, 1, Length[w[[2]]]}, {k, 1, Length[w[[3]]]}, {l, 1,Length[w[[4]]]}];

vec = Table[Count[Flatten[temp], 100*i], {i, 0, 4}]
vec.Table[Binomial[n + 5 - i, 5], {i, 0, 4}] // Expand


Out= 

{1, 338, 1225, 432, 4}

1 + (137 n)/6 + (551 n^2)/6 + (265 n^3)/2 + (475 n^4)/6 + (50 n^5)/3
```

**EDIT:** I got interested in investigating further @MikeEarnest 's generating function approach, but it did not aid my understanding on why the answer is so simple in this very particular case. From the perspective of the partial fraction decomposition, huge cancellations relying on trigonometric relations need to happen in order for the result to come out, and these are very difficult to monitor analytically. Of course, the method does provide the correct answer when the calculations are relayed to a computer, and this piece of code that implements it in Mathematica verifies that it does so:

```
temp = Integrate`ComplexApart[1/(1 - x)/(1 - x^5)/(1 - x^10)/(1 -x^20)/(1 - x^50)/(1 - x^100), x];

poly = ComplexExpand[
Re[
Assuming[n \[Element] Integers, 
Simplify[
Total[Assuming[{n >= 0}, SeriesCoefficient[#, {x, 0, n}]] & /@ Level[temp, 1]] /. n -> 100 n]] // N]];
Rationalize[#] & /@ Table[SeriesCoefficient[poly, {n, 0, i}], {i, 0, 5}].Table[n^i, {i, 0, 5}] 

Out: 1 + (137 n)/6 + (551 n^2)/6 + (265 n^3)/2 + (475 n^4)/6 + 50 n^5/3
```

Answer (score 1):

I can give the general strategy, but not the full solution.

In general, if you have a generating function of the form ${P(x)}/{Q(x)}$, where $P(x)$ and $Q(x)$ are polynomials, then you can extract a closed form for the coefficient of $x^n$ by finding the partial fraction decomposition for $P(x)/Q(x)$. If the distinct roots of $Q(x)$ are $r_1,\dots,r_k$, occurring with multiplicities $m_1,\dots,m_k$, then the partial fraction decomposition gives
$$
\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=b(x)+\sum_{i=1}^k\sum_{j=1}^{m_i}\frac{a_{i,j}}{(1-x/r_i)^j}\tag1
$$
where $b(x)$ is a polynomial. In the case where $\deg P<\deg Q$, as in your change-making generating function, $b(x)=0$, so I will assume $\deg P<\deg Q$ in the following general discussion.

We can quickly extract the coefficient of $x^n$ using
$$
[x^n]\frac1{(1-x/r)^{j}}=\frac1{r^n}\binom{n+j-1}{j-1}\tag2
$$
Therefore, we can write $[x^n]\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}$ as a linear combination of powers of roots of $Q(x)$ times certain binomial coefficients. More specifically, $\binom{n+j-1}{j-1}=\frac{1}{j!}(n)(n-1)\cdots(n-j+2)$ is a polynomial in $n$ with degree $j-1$. Therefore, if we combine $(1)$ with $(2)$, and convert all binomial coefficients to polynomials, we get
$$
[x^n]\frac{P(x)}{Q(x)}=\sum_{i=1}^k A_i(n) r_i^{-n},\tag3
$$
where for each $i\in \{1,\dots,k\}$, $A_i(n)$ is a polynomial in $n$ with $\deg A_i=m_i-1$.

Now, consider your problem, where $P(x)=1$ and $$Q(x)=(1-x)(1-x^5)(1-x^{10})(1-x^{20})(1-x^{50})(1-x^{100}).$$

Here, the roots of $Q$ are precisely the $100^\text{th}$ roots of unity. Let $\zeta$ be a primitive $100^\text{th}$ root of unity. Applying $(3)$, we see that
$$
\text{# ways make change for n}=\sum_{i=1}^{100} A_i(n) \zeta^{-in}
$$
This is not quite what you wanted; this is a linear combination of polynomials times exponentials of roots of unity, not just a polynomial. However, in the case were $n$ is a multiple of $100$, all of the $(\zeta)^{-in}$ factors become $1$, so this is just a polynomial, as required.

As you can probably see, all of these steps require a lot of computational effort, so they are best left to a computer algebra system.